# Error using ''error'' - not enough input arguments (Matlab R2021B)

Tags: matlab, error-handling

I am running a script in MATLAB r2021b but obtain the following eror message:

```
Error using error
Not enough input arguments.
Error in ivana_rsfa_logtransform (line 36)
        error;
```

Below I have pasted my code and you can see the error I get. Any advice would be very useful. I have attached comments in the script so that you understand what I am trying to do. :)

```matlab
rootdir = 'home/ivana/brain_scans';
for isub = 1:size(T1,1) % the data of my subjects are found in a table T1
    fn  = T1.f_rsfa{isub}; % fn is a variable containing subject's paths to folders with brain scans
    V   = spm_vol(fn) ;% variable fn needs to go into the spm_vol function in order to perform a transformation of the brain scans
    Y   = spm_read_vols(V); 
%% function to read in entire image volume- FORMAT [Y,XYZmm] = spm_read_vols(V,mask), where V is vector of mapped image volumes
    % to read in (from spm_vol) and mask is an implicit zero mask.
    % Y is a 4D matrix of image data, fourth dimension indexes images.
    
% spm_write_vol is a function to write an image volume to disk, setting scales and offsets as appropriate. The format is V = spm_write_vol(V,Y),where:
%   V (input)  - a structure containing image volume information (see spm_vol)
%   Y - a one, two or three dimensional matrix containing the image voxels
%   V (output) - data structure after modification for writing.
    idx = Y>0; % due to possible NaNs and 0s, we create a mask to only log transform images with + values
    if sum(Y(:)<0)
        error; % this is where I get the error
    end
    Ylog = Y;
    Ylog(idx) = log(Y(idx));
    Vtemp = V;
    Vtemp.fname = fullfile(rootdir,[Vtemp.fname]);% give filename and fullpath for the new image
    spm_write_vol(Vtemp,Ylog);
end
```

Comment: Typing `help error` will give you a short usage summary of the function `error`. Typing `doc error` will give you an extensive documentation page including examples: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/error.html — Reading the documentation for a function will very quickly show you how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you have not provided enough input arguments to the function. You need to provide more information to the function in order to run it properly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I have read the documentation for the function and understand I need to add more arguments, but am not quite sure how to fix the problem. Do I craft the error message myself or do I go with a default in Matlab, sorry I am still new to this. Even if I try:

`idx = Y>0; 
    if sum(Y(:)<0)
        error ('Error. /Input must be positive.');
end`

I get the same mistake.

Comment: I think it is because you are using <code>error()</code> as a function and not a method.
The syntax for <code>error()</code> is <code>error(msg, varargin)</code> where <code>msg</code> is a message and <code>varargin</code> is a variable number of arguments.
You are passing a single argument <code>'Error. /Input must be positive.'</code> and no variable arguments. Hence the error.
I would use <code>assert()</code> instead.
<code>assert(sum(Y(:)&lt;0)==0,'Error. /Input must be positive.');
</code>
Also give me a green tick if my answer was helpful. thanks @IvanaNeuroTic